# Ancestry: sorting on number of children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, ancestry

I want to sort my parent object on basis of number of children it has. [Ancestory](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) has this method 'child_ids' which return all the children ids. Is there a way I can use that to sort my parent objects?

```
 Project.order(child_ids.count)
```

or

```
 Project.order(Project.child_ids.count)
```

don't work. I guess that is obvious. Any other way to sort on basis of children can work too. Thanks!

**EDIT:**
look at ancestry column.Project id 2 has two children 6 and 9, both project 1 and 3 has one. I need to sort on basic of no of children, ie 2, 1, 3, rest...
[image]

Comment: post the schema of Project model so that the question can be better understood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should definitely be possible, you just need to join the two tables in order to use the `COUNT` of the `Project`s children.

Because you didn't include your schema, I made some assumptions about class names and foreign key/primary key names.  My solution assumes the child class has a table name of children, primary key of id, and a foreign key of project_id which references the Project class/projects table.

`Project.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN children on projects.id = children.project_id")
        .group("projects.id")
        .order("count(children.id) desc")`

It's necessary to use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` in order to include the `Project`s with zero children.

(edit: please add the schema for the child class as well as the class definitions of Project and its child class)

#### EDIT Wed May 20 07:34:58 PDT 2015

If ancestry holds the id of a `Project`s child `Project`, a self join would work.
What is the result of `Project.find(6).child_ids`?
What is the result of `Project.find(7).child_ids`?
I would expect `2` and `3` respectively.

`Project.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN projects p1 on projects.id = p1.ancestry
        .group("projects.id")
        .order("count(p1.ancestry) desc")`

Comment: There is no children table. The parent child relationship is defined in same class 'project'. Ancestry just adds an ancestry string column to the project and stores the parent_id in it, kinda like how one would make a tree.

Comment: @sonalkr132  the numbers in the ancestry column represent the `id`s of their parents?

Comment: yup! I can't tell you the details of the gem but thats what it is.